# Is there any emma plugin for jdeveloper 12c?

Tags: jdeveloper, emma

Similar to EclEmma which is a plugin on eclipse, is there any plugin for jdeveloper to see run junit tests and see the code coverage? I see EMMA integration plugin in jdeveloper but after installing wasn't able to see any difference and also could not get any documentation on what the plugin is supposed to do.. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but just in case someone came across it.
There is a blog post [here](http://ramannanda.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/code-coverage-in-adf-with-emma.html) explaining how to get Emma work with your JDeveloper. I also tested this on my latest JDeveloper 12c and it works fine.
Also regarding the documentation and how to use Emma it is all listed in their site [here](http://emma.sourceforge.net/)